# Caching vs Tempview

Tags: caching, apache-spark, parquet

I have a parquet file which I reading atleast 4-5 times within my application. I was wondering what is most efficient thing to do.

Option 1. While writing parquet file read it back on dataset and call cache. I am assuming by doing an immediate read I might use some existing hdfs/spark cache as part from write process.

Option 2. In my application when I need the dataset first time, after reading it cache it.

Option 3. While writing parquet file, after completion create a temp view out of it. In all subsequent usage, use the view.

I am also not very clear about efficiency of reading from tempview vs parquet dataset.

The datasets doesn't fit all into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cache dataset (Option 2).

- writing to disk will provide no improvements over Spark in-memory format
- temporary views don't cache.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I would also add a note about performance and data locality. Also why the other options are not a better choice :)

Comment: @eliasah I don't understand your comment :( Why data locality affects choice here?

Comment: Here is the thing, since the data doesn't fit in memory. Spark would probably need to persist on disk. Thus if the data-nodes are on the same computing need data is local to the executor and there won't be much improvement using the caching mechanism but you can skip this if you don't feel like talking about it

Comment: I'd rather you explain why the other options aren't good thought :)

Comment: @eliasah I don't fully understand though, so lets day I have 50 gb memory available, while the dataset is something like 80GB, so when I execute a map reduce, all 80 gb of data will first read in partition and then processes. Will there any difference caching will do in that case. Do you have a recommendation for this scenario, how data locality comes in picture and how it can help. PS I am a newbie to spark so appreciate your comments.

Comment: You might be interested in reading this https://www.quora.com/What-are-ways-to-improve-latency-in-a-Spark-single-node-cluster/answer/Elias-Abou-Haydar?srid=agpP&share=1df7144d

Comment: @eliasah Thank you!!! If you think there is something missing in the answer it is wiki now.

Comment: @LostInOverflow I'll try to write something when I have some spare time.